# How to run the sin(double x) method in C

Tags: c

I'm going through the C book, and I see this method declaration:

```
double sin(double x)
```

I am trying to run this example, here is what I have:

```
main()
{
   sin(1);
}
```

It prints nothing, how do I print `sin(x);` ?

Comment: Please learn C properly instead of trying to guess at its syntax and semantics by reading header files.

Comment: I am, I'm going through a book and using this function is one of the challenges. Don't be so quick to judge.

Comment: then use a [better book](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf) :-)

Comment: basically, if you're going through a book that asks you to open `math.h` without telling you a thing about the preprocessor and linking phase, then your book is terrible at teaching the C language.

Comment: the instructions were:

Use the math library! Add code to main.c that displays the sine of 1 radian. Show the number rounded to three decimal points. It should be 0.841. The sine function is declared like this:
double sin(double x);
 
and so, not knowing how to clearly understand the declaration was what confused me.

Comment: well, to me a good book should explain the basics (without necessary going to much into the details) about [*preprocessor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) and [*linking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_(software)) before asking a student to use a library, to avoid the kind of confusion you went into. Of course, the wikipedia explanations may not be as good as a [good book](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf) about the C language.

Comment: And you'll guess [which book](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf) I strongly advise you to read ;-) (hint: it has been written by [the creators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) of the C language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double sin(double x)
```

Is a function declared in the math.h header. It can be used anywhere you'd like - in main() or in any other function you write that is called within main(). However, the way you show it called in main will not do anything useful. The sin() function takes a double as an input and returns a double as an output, so you must store this result in order to do anything with it. For example:

```
#include <math.h>
void main()
{
  double x, y;
  x = 3.14159;
  y = sin(x);
}
```

Now y contains the value of the sine of x, which in this case would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should begin by opening a [C language book](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf), but here's the basic explanation:

test.c:

```
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  double x = sin(1);
}
```

there's a thing called "preprocessor" that parses your source code and generate a "pure C" source code that you can discover if you run:

```
gcc -E test.c
```

the `#include` directive is a preprocessor keyword (hint: they all begin with a `#`), that includes the file name given from the include path into the source code, and thus the *declaration* of the function is available from within the `test.c` source code.

The *declaration* is the form you pasted:

```
double sin(double x);
```

it only tells the compiler about the existence of the `sin()` function, it is not the `sin()` function itself.

But the *definition* of `sin()` is not in that source file. That's because there's another phase called "linking" that gets a compiled library's symbols and use them associated with symbols from the files. the `sin()` symbol is in one of such libraries.

That's for the basics, now it's time for you to read [a book](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf), because there's a lot more to learn about C to understand all that.